# Shift text and image down

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

Is there an easy way to shift the text and image down in the `Jumbotron` section of my website via HTML code?
I would like to shift the `text` and `image` down to the middle rather than the top.

Comment: Please provide the code tested.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Vertical align jumbotron](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32587001/vertical-align-jumbotron)